# What is the powdery mildew and why are my cucumbers not growing beyond 1 inch?

Tags: diseases, cucumbers

I have a healthy cucumber plant to all appearances.  There is some powdery mildew which I am trying to contain with a spray for that disease.  However, I have lots of buds which turn into tiny cucumbers, but they never get beyond 1 inch long then they turn yellow and die.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post some pictures so we get a good look at what is going on?  Also, additional information on how often you water the plant and last time you applied fertilizer would be helpful

Comment: Need pictures and any and everything you've done with soil, amendments, fertilizer and pesticides.  Powdery mildew is a big problem with cucumbers but especially plants that are compromised.  Try 1:9 milk and water to spray.  This really works!  Still need to discover the real problems not secondary.  Anything else will make the cucumbers inedible...maybe.  Need to know what you are using!  What you have done.  Are these cucumbers in pots or in the garden?  That is important to know!

Comment: Too high of nitrogen in the fertilizer will cause your reproductive growth to be worthless and minuscule.  Have you used compost?  Animal manure?  Was this manure decomposed or raw?

Comment: I believe the cucumber's female flowers have a little teeny-tiny fruit already attached, and if the flower doesn't get pollinated, the fruit will not develop at all. I had a (healthy looking) cucumber plant last year that had many cucumbers dropping off that way. After the flower dried up, it seemed like the fruit swelled a little, but soon turned yellow & withered at approx. 1 inch. A very *few* did become nice cucumbers. I thought it was because my plant was the only cucumber in the garden, and pollen availability was poor(?) Could this be your situation?- Is this even plausible?

Comment: My plant is the only one in my yard and is in a large pot.  I used Miracle Gro potting soil, Quick Start as the initial watering element and added a sprinkle of Miracle Gro Shake n' Feed (in early May).  By the end of May I had a large single cucumber appear. However just two days ago I discovered two cucumbers now about 6 inches long & seemingly healthy.  On 5/31 I added some Garden Tone to the plant; mildew is under control. A neighbor recommended watering with 1/2 Tab. Epsom Salt per 1/2 gal. water.  I just did that yesterday.  I'll have to wait to see the results.

Comment: @LorelC., I think you are on to something. Cucumbers have always grown for me back in the Northeast, but I recently moved to Texas and I noticed a wasp infestation and no bees. I wondered if there was a correlation between that and my cucumbers not growing to maturity. I have destroyed all the wasp nests. Bees are slowly starting to feel confident enough to approach and I do see some better growth on my cukes, but nothing to maturity yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Kristen! I used to have the same issue as I used to water my plants a little on the late side. Night watering in certain areas can really stir up the mold if the moisture and temperature are just right. Id like to encourage you to use the epsom salt that your neighbor suggested,as well as a simple spray of 1/2 WATER 1/2 MILK. I used whole milk and water, and using it in a spray bottle, I saturated the leaves that were affected by the mold and continued to every other day for a week. Also, washing the plants with water( just using your hose) can really help,too. Now,my elephant ears and calla lilies are just as vibrant as ever. You'll see a big difference with the things you already have at home. HAPPY GARDENING!

Answer (score -2):

My seedlings had a powdery mildew and I just let them dry out for a few days and scraped off what I could. I hope that helps.

Comment: Powdery mildew is caused by a fungus and its spores are microscopical, that's why scraping off doesn't eliminate the problem, it just delays the syptoms.